# Matchbox-Keyboard on input for QLineEdit PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, virtual-keyboard

What I'm trying to do is when a user (via a touchscreen) clicks on an editable QEditLine I want it to show the Matchbox-Keyboard for user input. When it is not clicked do not show the keyboard.

I've gone through the C documentation, and a few C examples, but I'm lost as too make the jump to Python. I see people mentioning setting the "focus" can someone explain this too me?

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog, QSlider, QComboBox, QCheckBox, QWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QLabel, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QRadioButton, QMessageBox, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt


class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'GUI TESTS'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 400
        self.statusBarMessage = "GUI TEST"
        self.currentSprite = 'TEST.png'
        self.btn1Active = False
        self.btn2Active = False
        self.btn3Active = False
        self.btn4Active = False
        self.btn5Active = False
        self.btn6Active = False
        self.btn7Active = False
        self.btn8Active = False
        self.saveLocationDir = ""
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.statusBar().showMessage(self.statusBarMessage)

        self.userNameLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.userNameLabel.move(0,125)
        self.userNameLabel.setText("What is your name?")
        self.userNameLabel.resize(120,20)

        self.nameInput = QLineEdit(self)
        self.nameInput.move(0,145)
        self.nameInput.resize(200,32)
        self.nameInput.setEchoMode(0)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def showKeyboard(self):
        command = "matchbox-keyboard"
        os.system(command)
```

Comment: can you add your code as well

Comment: I think I added the important parts. I just want to be able to bring up the keyboard when they click on the QLineEdit widget.

Comment: try adding self.nameInput.clicked.conect(self.showKeyboard)

Comment: I tried that before, what I got was... self.nameInput.clicked.connect(self.showKeyboard)
AttributeError: 'QLineEdit' object has no attribute 'clicked'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to override the events method by assigning a function `self.nameInput.mousePressEvent = self.showKeyboard` since the tasks of the `mousePressEvent` of the `QLineEdit` are lost and could cause unexpected events.

Also, `mousePressEvent` is not the appropriate event since you can press the `QLineEdit` many times and it would be called back to the keyboard.

A better option is to launch it in `focusInEvent` and delete it in `focusOutEvent`:

```
import sys
import subprocess
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class MatchBoxLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    def focusInEvent(self, e):
        try:
            subprocess.Popen(["matchbox-keyboard"])
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass

    def focusOutEvent(self,e):
        subprocess.Popen(["killall","matchbox-keyboard"])

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('GUI TESTS')

        widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(widget)

        self.userNameLabel = QLabel("What is your name?")
        self.nameInput = MatchBoxLineEdit()

        lay.addWidget(self.userNameLabel)
        lay.addWidget(self.nameInput)

        self.setGeometry(
            QStyle.alignedRect(
                Qt.LeftToRight,
                Qt.AlignCenter,self.sizeHint(), 
                qApp.desktop().availableGeometry()
                )
            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = App()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Do I need to use layouts or can I use the hard coded locations? When I try to implement this into my hardcoded position areas it loads up an additional window?

Comment: @user9453545 It is not necessary to use the layouts, I only did it to have an order in my example, in a few moments I will publish using your template.

Comment: @user9453545 
I do not like to place unnecessary code in my solutions, for example the variables self.btnXActive are unnecessary and do not help at all. If you are going to use QMainWindow you should add the widget to the centralwidget, not the QMainWindow. For more information read: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#details. 
If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the [tour]

Comment: My bad I thought I replied. But everything worked for me perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog, QSlider, QComboBox, QCheckBox, QWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QLabel, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QRadioButton, QMessageBox, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt


class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'GUI TESTS'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 400
        self.statusBarMessage = "GUI TEST"
        self.currentSprite = 'TEST.png'
        self.btn1Active = False
        self.btn2Active = False
        self.btn3Active = False
        self.btn4Active = False
        self.btn5Active = False
        self.btn6Active = False
        self.btn7Active = False
        self.btn8Active = False
        self.saveLocationDir = ""
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.statusBar().showMessage(self.statusBarMessage)

        self.userNameLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.userNameLabel.move(0,125)
        self.userNameLabel.setText("What is your name?")
        self.userNameLabel.resize(120,20)

        self.nameInput = QLineEdit(self)
        self.nameInput.move(0,145)
        self.nameInput.resize(200,32)
        self.nameInput.setEchoMode(0)
        self.nameInput.mousePressEvent=self.showKeyboard

    @pyqtSlot()
    def showKeyboard(self,event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            QtWidgets.QLineEdit.mousePressEvent(self, event)
            command = "matchbox-keyboard"
            os.system(command)
```

You can override mousePressEvent and achieve that functionality

Comment: How do you get input from the matchbox to the GUI app? I had to removed the QtWidgets.QLineEdit.mousePressEvent(self, event) line otherwise it wouldn't run.